# Finding the joint cdf from a pdf

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference

> Suppose the joint pdf $(X,Y)$ is $$f(x,y) = 24y(x-y) \ \ \text{for} \ \ 0 < y < x < 1$$
>   (the support of this joint pdf is a triangular region bounded by the lines $y=0$,$x=1$, and $y=x$)
>
> How would you find the cdf $F(x,y)$

Attempted solution: I know that $$F(x,y) = \int \int f(x,y) dxdy$$

I just don't know what the bounds for the integrals would be and why? Also, I can't seem to calculate the CDF.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Integrating pdf is the way to go.

Now, to find the CDF, you need to compute
$$ Pr(X\leq x,Y \leq y) = \int \int_R f(X,Y)dXdY$$ where R is the appropriate region of integration.

---

Now, the region of integration will depend on the values of $x$ and $y$. We consider two cases: (1) $y>x$, and (2) $y \le x$. The best is to draw each of the cases and see what restrictions do these inequalities impose on $R$.

Case 1 ($y>x$): Here $Y \in [0,x]$ and $X \in [Y,x]$.

Case 2 ($y \le x$): Here we need to split $R$ into two regions of integration. First region is $Y \in[0,y]$ and $X \in [Y,y]$. Second region is $Y \in [0,y]$ and $X \in [y,x]$.

---

Computing the above integral using the regions of integration derived above we get

$$ Pr(X\leq x,Y \leq y)= x^4  \text{ if   } x\leq y \\ 
Pr(X\leq x,Y \leq y)= y^4 + 2y^2\left( 3 x^2 - 4 xy +y^2\right)  \text{ if x>y   } $$

Comment: Hi, this is definitely a dumb question but I don't understand how Case 1 exists (in this problem). The joint pdf is defined as non-zero for 0<y<x<1, so wouldn't the case of y>x be irrelevent here? And could you maybe write out a bit more information about how you calculated the bounds of integration in Case 2?